# BLDC MOSFET Driver Bridge - High side not achieving full voltage, low side always grounded

Tags: mosfet, pwm, brushless-dc-motor, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

I have been designing a BLDC controller using IR2101 gate drivers to control high/low MOSFETs. Please see schematics below.

After soldering everything on and testing circuits, I am not getting the desired outcome. Everything is powered via a 52v DC source and I step down to 5v and 12v for the MCU and drivers (not in schematics). Using my PIC16F MCU, I supply PWM signals to the high side of A and low side of B to ground, however the maximum voltage on my meter shows 15v and not 52v as needed. When I attach a 24v (I know) LED to see if it powers, the voltage drops significantly to a max of 2v at 10bit PWM signal (100% duty); I tried different frequencies and pulse periods with little luck. Something is of course wrong here and I believe in order to switch the high side, the gate voltage needs to be higher than the source. I have a bootstrap setup to charge and pump. I used [TI's calculations](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua887/slua887.pdf?ts=1674490202298&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A19%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C0%2C575.8%2C0%5D) to determine the size of the capacitor:
Cg = Qg/Vq1g and landed at .15uF. I also tried a 10uF capacitor and the bootstrap max voltage achieved was 22v but at the gate of the high MOSFET, it still is only about 13v.

The [IR2101](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_ir2101_DS_v01_00_EN-1732415.pdf) should switch up to 600v.

Best PWM specs:

- 5v
- 1.024ms
- 976.56Hz 10bit (1023)

**Questions:**

- Is my bootstrap setup incorrectly?
- Is my PWM setup incorrectly? I simply supply 2 separate PWM outputs in a While loop.
- I have a small resistor before gate and a large value to suppress the vibrations when not switching. Could these be the issue?
- Am I supposed to have all three phases wired up for the bootstraps to charge properly?
- When I only turn on the high side, the low side MOSFETs are always grounded which seems incorrect. These MOSFETS have a pad as the drain so I am curious if they are inherently supposed to be grounded when not switched. This seems wrong as don't we have to turn the low side as the ground source for the BLDC phase?

[image]

Comment: _"however the maximum voltage on my **meter** shows 15v"_ - Where are you measuring the voltage? Why are you not using an oscilloscope? _"Is my PWM setup incorrectly? I simply supply 2 separate PWM outputs in a While loop."_ - This sounds very wrong. Please show PWM waveforms with the timing relationship between them. Are you also applying 6 step commutation?

Comment: This style of gate drive cannot support 100% high side duty, and your multimeter will average your PWM, not display the maximum. Best to get a scope on it.

Comment: My scope broke recently so I used a meter and tested the source at the high side of A as + and source at the low side of B or C as the ground. Using a pot, I do see the voltage shift from 0-15v but that is the max. Not applying 6 step commutation as I not that far yet. This is my first time doing this and I also need to measure the back EMF later. I firstly want to confirm this setup/schematic and if there are initial tests I can do to make sure it is correct.

Comment: `When I only turn on the high side, the low side MOSFETs are always grounded which seems incorrect.` What is the observation giving rise to this statement? The low side sources *are* connected to GND.

Comment: I did a basic 6 step commutation on/off of PWM, connected BLDC, and nothing happens. I tap the BLDC phases with a 12v battery and it spins fine. I am getting voltages on all the PWM inputs, the gate, the source, etc. Everything seems fine but no switching. 

I am doing high side of A and low side of B PWM to LoadDutyValue(1023) in code which is full scale. No voltage measured and no movement. If I unplug the motor, then there is some voltage on the phase lines. 

Would someone let me know what to do and look for exactly with a scope? Just got a new handheld.

Comment: ugggh figured out what was wrong...on my PCB design I forgot to ground the MCU to high voltage source also. I think it was not closing the logic circuit and nothing was happening. I did a basic test to switch an LED and 1x MOSFET by feeding the gate 5v. It works well but it does not switch to the full 52v rather just about 8v on the LED. Not sure what that happens. I tried various PWM settings but for some reason the LED is dim and way brighter when connected directly to battery.